# Setting up SSL / Https in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, https, server

i have following code

```
enconst https = require("https");

 const app = require("./app");
  var fs = require("fs");

 var options = {
     hostname: "sharkfood-portal.de",

  key: fs.readFileSync("/opt/certs/_.sharkfood-portal.de_private_key.key"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(
  "/opt/certs/_.sharkfood-portal.de_ssl_certificate_INTERMEDIATE.cer"
    ),
    requestCert: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    };

   const port = process.env.PORT || 12103;

     const server = https.createServer(options, app);

     server.listen(port);
```

But get this error...

Error: unable to verify the first certificate
at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1502:34)